# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer preview position starts under navigation bar(toolbar)

Tags: swift, swift3, avcapturesession

Hi I am a new bee to swift. trying to use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer for my custom camera app. but the image captured is not as same as the preview. 
tried following

```
 self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

here is my code snippet

```
 self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer!, at: 0 )
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
         captureSession.startRunning()

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true[capture screen][1]
```

[image: result [![enter image description here]image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDQCc.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDQCc.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view position start with (x:0,y:0) be default in UINavigationController. The navigationbar overlap the view by 64px(20px = Status bar, 44px= Navigation bar) Height. You have two options fix video preview layer  frame:

**Option1:**

change Y position of previewLayer,

```
var frame = self.view.layer.bounds
frame.origin.y = 64
frame.size.height = frame.size.height-64
self.previewLayer.frame = frame
```

**Option2:**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false,
```

add this line in ViewdidLoad() method.
by default `isTranslucent = true`, assign `false` means, the View frame position starts from x:0 and y:64.

no need to change your code by using **Option2**

Comment: tried this. it was only showing the preview correctly. not the output image